# IOS different xibs for different screen sizes

Tags: ios, uitableview, xib

I am new to IOS programming and would like to display a square image in a `UITableViewCell`, so size would be 320x320 or 375x375 for iphones 5 and 6 for instance.

Can this be done with a single xib file or two different `XIB`?

If it's 2 `XIB`, what is a good screen size test for registering the correct nib as a tableview cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a single xib. Using autolayout, you have to add a constraint to specify that your cell's height should be the same as its width. This way, if the width changes your height is automatically updated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use single XIB using AutoLayout and Adaptative Layout provided by the `Size Classes` : [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html).

Size Classes allow you to deal with different sizes. **[Regular]** - **[Compact]**

You should found [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial) what you are looking for.